# How to install vc++ redistributable without windows installer

Tags: visual-c++, windows-installer, windows-server-2012, redistributable

In our product we had to disable the "windows installer" service (security-wise).
In Windows 2012 it is not possible to do so with sc.exe, so we had to change the value of the service in the registry
(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\msiserver ---> start = 4)

Now, as an upgrade process of our product, we need to install
"VC++ 2013 redist"

1. Is it possible to install this package without using windows installer?
2. Or, is it possible to start a "disabled" windows installer service without restarting the machine?

Comment: You don't generally need to reboot the machine to start a service.  You should be able to change the startup type to manual, start the service, then set the startup type back to disabled.  (I'm doubtful that there is any real benefit to disabling the windows installer service, however.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of installing the VC++2013 runtime using Windows Installer you can put the needed files in the directory of your executable:

> you can directly install redistributable Visual C++ DLLs in the application local folder, which is the folder that contains the executable application file.

(from [Redistributing Visual C++ Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299%28v=vs.120%29.aspx))

Comment: On Windows 11 this will not work anymore. Windows 11 forces to load Side by Side DLLs from SXS directory. If the DLL's are not there you get error 14001. It will not even work if you copy the DLLs into the System32 directory.